# How to read international character sets using CoreText on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, fonts, internationalization, core-text

I am trying to load international character glyphs on iOS using CoreText, but I am having some trouble.  I am trying to use the following function call to create the font:

```
CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage(kCTFontUIFontUser, 15, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"zh-CN");
```

However, this does not return Chinese characters.  Instead I get the regular default en-US font file.  What am i doing wrong here?  Also, is there a way to get any font, not just the system fonts, or maybe set the font used by these constants?  Is there another function call I should be using?

Furthermore, is it possible to determine which built in iOS fonts are capable of rendering international characters and which are not?  I would really hate to have to load in my own TTF file, but if the font we want can't support international characters by default, we will have no choice.  I am aware that there are certain fonts that support international characters such as "ArialHebrew", but I was hoping that we could use the same font face for all character sets.

Thanks.

EDIT - I also tried the language code with an underscore instead of a dash; no luck.

Comment: Have the same problem here, do you have any solutions by now?

Comment: I gave up trying to use CoreText and ended up using Freetype.